# How to avoid keys in a plain file?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using Node.js and Mysql,I would like to encrypt the data on my database.
I would like to know how can I avoid storing plain keys in a file that can be easy find, doing `AES_ENCRYPT(text, key)` does not make sense to me because I pass a plain key that someone can read without problem on the server.

Any advice?
Asymmetric cryptography?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would encrypt any data prior to sending it to the MySQL server in order to prevent any unencrypted data appearing within logs.  The following information detauls the Node.js crypto module which should do as you need.  That way all that is leaving your server is encrypted strings which are of far less use without the key.

Node.js encryption module docs : http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html

Comment: That link leads to seriously outdated documentation. This is better: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html

Comment: Thanks for that @LinusGThiel - I'm more familiar with Coldfusion but the same principle applies :)

Comment: @Simonatmso.net node.js run on the server, how can i use "crypto" module on the client??

Comment: I'm afraid I've no idea on that, it would expose your key though if you were to do that.  I would advise setting up an HTTPS connection from client to server, and perform cryptography on the server thus keeping key private to the server.  For anything more specific than above you'll need to refine your question with specifics as to what you are trying to do / how you are currently trying to do it.

Comment: @Dail cryptography is not meant for client side, since it's code is exposed, using https is the recommended way.

Comment: If in doubt, NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER trust ANYTHING the client sends you.  EVER.  AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the user supply the key on startup, using the `readline` module:

Your app:

```
module.exports = function(key) {
    var app = // ...
}
```

Your start script:

```
var readline = require('readline')
  , interface = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout, null);

interface.question("Please supply a key", function(key) {
    // load your app, supplying the key
    require("./app")(key);
    interface.close();
    process.stdin.destroy();
});
```